# Guidelines to debug REINFORCE-type algorithms?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pytorch, nlp, policy-gradients

I implemented a self-critical policy gradient (as described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04304.pdf)), for text summarization.

However, after training, the results are not as high as expected (actually lower than without RL...).

**I'm looking for general guidelines on how to debug RL-based algorithms.**

---

I tried :

- **Overfitting on small datasets** (~6 samples) : I could increase the average reward , but it does not *converge*. Sometimes the average reward would go down again.
- **Changing the learning rate** : I changed the learning rate and see its effect on small dataset. From my experiment I choose quite big learning rate (`0.02` vs `1e-4` in the paper)
- **Looking at how average reward evolve as training (on full dataset) goes** : Average reward significantly does not move...

Answer (score 1):

For a deep dive into all sorts of possible issues that can come up in practical application of policy gradient, have a look at this paper:

[A Closer Look at Deep Policy Gradients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02553)

Some common ways to improve policy gradient methods is:

1. Confine the updates to a "trust region" near the current policy (see TRPO and PPO).
2. Introduce a value network (called Critic in Actor-Critic) which can be used to subtract a baseline that reduces variance in policy-gradient learning.

Answer (score 0):

The only resource I could find so far :

https://github.com/williamFalcon/DeepRLHacks

---

For my specific case, I made a few errors :

- Frozen some part of the network that shouldn't be frozen
- Wrong learning rate

Even if I could overfit a small dataset, it didn't mean anything : while training on the whole dataset, the average reward was not going up.

You should look for a reward going up.

---

*I'm not accepting this answer as I believe it is not complete : it lacks general and systematic guidelines to debug a Reinforcement Learning algorithm.*